# How to pick the right ANDROID_EABI?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building libopenssl for Android on Ubuntu. I noticed that one of the steps is to define the following two terms:

```
_ANDROID_API="android-16"
_ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.6"
```

The value "android-16" for _ANDROID_API makes sense as this corresponds to Android version 4.1, the minimum level that we support.

However, I am confused about picking the right value for _ANDROID_EABI. If I look under $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains, I see that I have arm-linux-androideabi-4.6, arm-linux-androideabi-4.8, and arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 available. How do I decide which one is the right one for me? Is there any relationship between android_eabi version and the minimum version of Android that we support?

Also, some other libraries that I am building does not require any _ANDROID_EABI to be specified. If they are picking an EABI autmatically, would it be a problem when all the libraries are linked into a single .so file? Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the naming used in those openssl build scripts is confusing. You don't pick an "EABI version" (EABI is the name of the ABI currently used on ARM), you pick a toolchain version (which the openssl build scripts call "the version of the EABI tools", even though it can be a non-EABI toolchain like for x86).

There's no relationship between the toolchain version used and the minimum Android version supported.

To decide for yourself which toolchain to use, do as you'd choose your compiler version in any other situation. Newer major versions might potentially be (slightly) less mature, but may optimize better.

If libraries don't require you to name the toolchain directly, they may either have hardcoded a choice for you (a gcc 4.6 based toolchain has been part of the NDK for quite some time, while the other ones are newer - earlier there also was a gcc 4.4 based one), or may pick whichever is the default in the NDK.

To find the one that is default in the NDK, you could do something like this:

```
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=<ndk>/samples/hello-jni <ndk>/ndk-build DUMP_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX APP_ABI=armeabi
```

(You can point to any NDK project with the path, as long as it doesn't override the toolchain version. And instead of DUMP_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX you could also use DUMP_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION.)

Also note that the NDK has deprecated the GCC 4.6 toolchain that is default right now, and will probably remove it (and bump the default to one of the newer ones) - see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/q8jchajqKIo for some discussion on that matter.

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear description and also to point out that 4.6 toolchain is being deprecated.

Comment: If it helps, I used GCC 4.7.0 (or 4.8.0...I forget) to build libopenssl on Android...either one of those versions of GCC should work for you if available in the NDK.  Also, I was informed by the GCC maillist that it is better to use the higher point releases...i.e. 4.8.2, 4.8.3...as they include important patches/fixes.